# How I can let users (of my website) write maths in my contact form?

Tags: wordpress, math, plugins

Is there any way my users can write maths (using latex for instance) in a contact form?

I'm using wordpress but cannot find any suitable plugins.

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: What do you mean by write math? can you be more specific..

Comment: Which plugin you have used for contact form ?

Comment: By write maths I mean be able to write all maths symbols and form complicated equations etc

Comment: I've used contact form 7

Answer (score 0):

Use MathJax-LaTeX, it is what Math SE uses.

You can check out how to enable it in wordpress at [MathJax documentation](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v1.1-latest/platforms/wordpress.html).

Answer (score -1):

You should use the CAPTCHA plugin for this.

In wordpress there are so many captcha plugins.You can use one of them.

Here is a link with maths captcha: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-math-captcha/